# What is an Endless Phrase™?

Tags: pattern, english

I've been itching to try and make one of these for a while since [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee) started posting them. I feel like this one might not be challenging enough, but I'll see what you guys make of it.

The following table contains two columns. Each of the phrases in the left column has a property for which I call it an Endless Phrase™, that the phrases in the right column lack.

[image: a list of endless and non-endless phrases]

- The appearance of letters, including capitalization, has no bearing on the rule.

Can you figure out what the pattern is?

Comment: -1 for not telling us who JLee is and expecting us to look it up for ourselves.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I put a link in; is that better?

Comment: +1 nice puzzle! one thing I learned from feedback: although the pictures look better, some users like to have a copyable list in text form (some because they cannot view images online at work, and some for other reasons), so if you add that at the end, it will make them happy and you'll reach more people.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rho Your last example for "not endless phrases" has a mistake. :)

Comment: And I spent like two hours checking for errors. >_> Thanks for catching.

Comment: Is "abysmal break-in device" better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An endless phrase is one in which:

> Taking the last letter(s) of a phrase and applying it to the beginning allows you to create (at least) one new word. I suspect it allows you to continue for longer than that, but I'm struggling to do that

Examples:

> **listen** to the paintin**g** -> glisten
> **A cle**ated shoe in a **barn** -> barnacle
> **ter**rible crow**bar** -> barter

As ever, this doesn't work with the non-endless phrases

End results from each line:

> 1)cob
> 2)glisten (though glis is an animal genus, apparently)
> 3)leader
> 4)wad
> 5)agog
> 6)erase
> 7)local
> 8)cat
> 9)best
> 10)black
> 11)eon
> 12)llama
> 13)barnacle
> 14)net
> 15)source
> 16)least
> 17)whelp
> 18)shear (or even she)
> 19)men
> 20)art

Comment: You've got the right idea, but the words are shorter than that (sometimes only three letters). :\

Comment: Er, the words are _usually_ shorter than that, but "barnacle" is correct.